# Recoding data frame column based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I recode a column based on values from other columns? Say I have the below data frame and I want to recode `df$Col3` so that the value is 0 if `df$Col1 == x` and `df$Col2 == a`.

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(rep("x",3),rep("y",3),rep("x",4)),letters[c(1:5,3,4:1)],1:10)
> names(df)<-c("Col1","Col2","Col3")
> df
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1     x    a    1
2     x    b    2
3     x    c    3
4     y    d    4
5     y    e    5
6     y    c    6
7     x    d    7
8     x    c    8
9     x    b    9
10    x    a   10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
> df$Col3  <- with(df, ifelse(Col1=='x' & Col2=='a', 0, Col3))
> df
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1     x    a    0
2     x    b    2
3     x    c    3
4     y    d    4
5     y    e    5
6     y    c    6
7     x    d    7
8     x    c    8
9     x    b    9
10    x    a    0
```

Comment: Elegant but quite slow... especially due to ifelse

Comment: @Michele What do you mean with "quite slow"? Did you benchmark? `ifelse` is vectorized R function, so can you explain what "quite slow" is ?

Comment: Hi, it isn't actually 'quite' slow. Please check the EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df[which(df$Col1=="x" & df$Col2=="a"),"Col3"] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
> df$Col3[df$Col1 == "x" & df$Col2 == "a"] <- 0

> df
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1     x    a    0
2     x    b    2
3     x    c    3
4     y    d    4
5     y    e    5
6     y    c    6
7     x    d    7
8     x    c    8
9     x    b    9
10    x    a    0
```

EDIT: 
@Jilber

```
f1 <- function() 
  df$Col3[df$Col1 == "x" & df$Col2 == "a"] <- 0

f2 <- function() 
  df$Col3  <- with(df, ifelse(Col1=='x' & Col2=='a', 0, Col3))

library(microbenchmark)

> microbenchmark(f1(),f2(), times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq median     uq     max neval
 f1() 65.749 67.673 68.315 69.597 123.158  1000
 f2() 80.823 83.068 84.030 85.312 207.187  1000
```

Nothing incredible, I know. Your method, including an alternative value when the condition is not fulfilled, is just more general and so a bit slower. Basically, in this case, the evaluation of the negative values in the `test` parameter of `ifelse` is not needed 'cause you would be overwriting the original values with themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset a data frame using the [] brackets. 
   The format is like this: df[conditions or subset rows, condition or subset columns]

```
df[df$Col1==x & df$Col2==a, df$Col3]  <- 0
```