# rewriting multiple columns based on different columns

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, square-bracket

I have a bit of a problem with my code, I solved it, but now i kind of want to find a more efficient way of doing so, since I'm positive there is one.

I have a data of 120K people, with 262 variables, and I need to update some columns in the data based on another set of columns.
I have tried multiple solutions and found one here '[Recoding data frame column based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957579/recoding-data-frame-column-based-on-multiple-columns)' 
but, I need to do this to multiple columns (6 in my data) twice. I'm hoping there is a better way of doing this than write 12 lines that does exactly the same thing, which in my experience is a a great source for mistakes.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  "x1" = c(1,0,2,0,5,3,2),
  "y1" = c(12,14,13,14,12,11,13),
  "x2" = c(3,2,0,1,2,5,3),
  "y2" = c(11,13,14,12,13,12,11)
)
dat

# 1st try. works slowly
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat$x1[i] == 2){dat$y1 <- 8}
  if(dat$x2[i] == 2){dat$y2 <- 8}
}

# 2nd try. doesn't work. (Tried multiple variation)
dat$y1 <- ifelse(dat$x1 == 2,dat$y1 <- 8,dat$y1)

# 3rd try. works efficiently, but annoying as hell to code.
dat$y1[dat$x1 == 2] <- 8
dat$y2[dat$x2 == 2] <- 8
```

Thank you in advance. (this is my first question,please tell me if I have done something wrong, or if I didn't phrase myself eloquently or clearly...)

Abe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you don't want to repeat same code several times. To achieve this you can wrap it in a loop like this:

```
myColsCheck <- c("x1", "x2")
myColsUpdate <- c("y1", "y2")
for (n in 1:length(myColsCheck)) {
  dat[dat[, myColsCheck[n]] == 2, c(myColsUpdate[n])] <- 8
}
dat
```

Comment: In the end I did what you did... My problem is an inherent dislike for loops in R..seems wrong... Thank you!!

Comment: Loops overs meta-data (e.g. columns) are not that bad. Loops over data usually are bad.

Comment: my meta-data (LOVE the new word you just taught me..) is going over rows...31,000 of them..it's not ideal...